# How to check if all values of a dictionary are 0

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to check if all the values, i.e values corresponding to all keys in a dictionary are 0. Is there any way to do it without loops? If so how?

Comment: How did you do it with a loop?

Comment: i iterated through the dictionary and checked all values i.e values corresponding to all keys if even one wasn't true i changed the flag value and broke out of loop.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

use `all()`:

```
all(value == 0 for value in your_dict.values())
```

`all` returns `True` if all elements of the given iterable are true.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `[any()]`<sup>1</sup> method, basically it checks for boolean parameters, but 0 will act as False in this case, and any other number as True.

**PY3**:

```
dict1 = {"a": 0, "b": 1}
dict2 = {"a": 0, "b": 0}

print(not any(dict1.values()))
print(not any(dict2.values()))
enter code here
```

Try this code PY2:

```
dict1 = {"a": 0, "b": 1}
dict2 = {"a": 0, "b": 0}

print not any(dict1.itervalues())
print not any(dict2.itervalues())
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Edit 2: one sidenote/caution, calling any() with an empty list of elements will return False.

Edit 3: Thanks for comments, updated the code to reflect python 3 changes to dictionary iteration and print function.

<sup>1</sup>: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Comment: `all` is lazy as well.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham While you are correct, he asked for a none looping solution (even though under the hood this is still looping), this is the best I can give without looping, and I'm under the assumption the input is normalized/correct.

Comment: @Fanchi, based on the title of the question I think  it is important to make the distinction for any future readers.

Comment: Now it's dict.values()

Comment: I wanted to make an edit but I couldn't make an edit request. the reason: the old answer of Python2 didn't work for me although it was on top I didn't see the solution appearance from the first look, I had to look more carefully, I hope this can be edited to make the Python3 (current version) more appealing for future readers. some **bold font**?

Answer (score 10):

With `all`:

```
>>> d = {1:0, 2:0, 3:1}
>>> all(x==0 for x in d.values())
False
>>> d[3] = 0
>>> all(x==0 for x in d.values())
True
```

No matter whether you use `any` or `all`, the evaluation will be lazy. `all` returns `False` on the first falsy value it encounters. `any` returns `True` on the first truthy value it encounters.

Thus, `not any(d.values())` will give you the same result for the example dictionary I provided. It is a little shorter than the `all` version with the generator comprehension. Personally, I still like the `all` variant better because it expresses what you want without the reader having to do the logical negation in his head.

There's one more problem with using `any` here, though:

```
>>> d = {1:[], 2:{}, 3:''}
>>> not any(d.values())
True
```

The dictionary does not contain the value 0, but `not any(d.values())` will return `True` because all values are falsy, i.e. `bool(value)` returns `False` for an empty list, dictionary or string.

In summary: readability counts, be explicit, use the `all` solution.

Comment: The `not any` would evaluate to True if all the values are _falsey_, so it's different than testing if all values are equal to `0`.

Answer (score 4):

You may also do it the other way using any :

```
>>> any(x != 0 for x in somedict.values())
```

If it returns True , then all the keys are not 0 , else all keys are 0