# Python Dict getting all the key values

Tags: python

I created a dict and set all the values to 1 now I'm trying to write a condition if all key values == 1 but confused how to do it can anyone please help in this.

```
server = {
"server_2": "",
"server_3": "",
"server_4": "",
"server_5": "",
"server_6": ""
        }
testing = 'yes'
if testing == 'yes':
    server['server_2'] = 1
    server['server_3'] = 1
    server['server_4'] = 1
    server['server_5'] = 1
    server['server_6'] = 1
```

After this I need to check if all the key value is 1, is there any way to do that.

Comment: `if all(v == 1 for v in server.values()): # do stuff` :will do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if all values of a dictionary are 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253971/how-to-check-if-all-values-of-a-dictionary-are-0).

Comment: Only difference between this and duplicate is `0` and `1`.

Comment: Why to check if all values are `1` if you just set them? And if you are simply trying to set all values to `1` wouldn't it just be easier to do: `for key in server: server[key] = 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if all(server.values()):
     # do stuff
```